# Command to release the best amount of Memory Ram

Tags: kernel, ram

I have `Ubuntu` 18.04

For example if Ubuntu is just started the `Memory Ram` has 2.0 GB, if I just open `Firefox` the component increases (how is expected) lets say to 2.5GB. If I close Firefox (`Ctrl + Q`), I would expect that the value returns to 2.0GB. Well it does not happen how is expected, for example: the `Memory Ram` returns to 2.2GB (and not 2.0GB).

I have this behavior with other programs apart of `Firefox`.

Is there a command where I can free in general all the `memory ram`? At least to the best acceptable minimum value according to the OS itself after to execute the command.

The goal is after to execute some "heavy" software development tools and servers (therefore when they have just been closed), release the best amount of resources of these two components.

**Note:** not sure if the `Kernel` has this behavior too (such as `Kernel Task` in `MacOS`), it because both are Unix based

Comment: Linux does cache stuff in memory, but will give up the memory if needed. If you want to force it do as sudo `sync` followed by `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`. Check before and after with `free -m`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a program terminates, RAM used by that program is freed. Memory used by shared libraries will be released if no other program uses that library.

If the data reads and writes data to disk, it will be cached if there's free RAM available. This cache will be kept until new data replaces it, or it is needed for programs and not caching.

To view the information, `free -m` will give you information.

```
$ free  -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           5950        2292        1444           9        2213        3358
Swap:          4084         350        3734
```

In this case, the total amount of RAM is 5950MiB, 2292MiB is *actually in use, and 1444MiB is not in use in any sense. Additionally, 2213MiB is used for caching. The cache and free is available for immediate use, for a total available memory of 3358MiB.

When you exit your program, you will see that used drops, but the `buff/cache` column does not change. However, this doesn't matter, as memory used for cache is available for use whenever you need it.

So in short: Let Linux manage your memory. There's no need to do it manually.

Comment: I see the logic, thanks for the explanation, just being curious: from where exactly comes from 3358? It is a generated number by your report right? I mean, according with your context `free` + `cache` should give 3358, but really the math (1444 + 2213) represents: 3657 and not 3358 how is expected.

Comment: @ManuelJordan :  see the man pages for free, particularly the description for the "available field" because it is an estimate and takes other things into account. If you want more detail then do `cat /proc/meminfo`.

Comment: Thanks for the other command. I am going to do the respective research